# NullReferenceException with $expand in OData Web Api controller

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, nullreferenceexception, asp.net-core-3.1

**Environment:** Net Core 3.1 Web Api, Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.4.0-beta

I've an OData api controller CustomersController that it's working fine, but $expand always returns NullReferenceException. Customer has a one to many Contacts and Addresses.

This is the code of action method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var customers = _context.Customers;

            _logger.LogInfo($"Returned {customers.Count()} customers from database.");

            return Ok(customers);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Something went wrong inside Get customers action: {ex.Message}");
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
```

And this is the customer object definition:

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Name can't be longer than 100 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Commercial name can't be longer than 100 characters")]
    public string CommercialName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tax code is required")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Tax code can't be longer than 25 characters")]
    public string TaxCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Email can't be longer than 250 characters")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Url can't be longer than 250 characters")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext configuration:

```
        // Table
        builder.ToTable("Customers");
        builder.HasKey(b => b.CustomerId);

        // Relationships
        builder.HasMany(b => b.Contacts)
            .WithOne(b => b.Customer)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.CustomerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasMany(b => b.Addresses)
            .WithOne(b => b.Customer)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.CustomerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I have another controller but with one to one relationships and this controller works fine with $expand with the same code in action method.

Any idea about what is failing?
Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this is an issue with OData Web Api library version.

This is the issue:

Regards

Comment: Sorry, this is the right url... https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2080